# To be + gerund with agent as subject complement

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> My friend asks: Why  didn't you come to the party last night?
> I say: The reason was my roommate feeling sick, so I had to stay home and take care of him.

I wonder, is it correct to use: subject + to be + gerund with agent (which is subject complement in the sentence)?

Of course I can use:

> The reason was my roommate, (who was) feeling sick... . (non defining)

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say _The reason was that my roommate felt sick_.

Comment: Grammaticality (I'm sure the ACC-ing can be justified here, though the POSS-ing [' the reason was my roommate's feeling sick'] perhaps makes more sense) is not the only hurdle sentences have to leap. Kate's alternative would make you sound like an English-speaker rather than an EFL student or 19th century grammarian.

Comment: Personally I don't much care for sentences that start with "the reason was."  I'd say something like, "I had to stay home and take care of my roommate who wasn't feeling well" or "My roommate wasn't etc."

Comment: In conversation, you could just say “Because my roommate was feeling sick . . . “. You can leave out “because,” too.